# How to implement a service layer using Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am curious what the best way is to implement a service layer using Ember.js.
A can not really find any suggestions about it in the Ember Guide.
For example I have some validation code that I could use in more than one controllers, and I don't want to copy&paste them into all of them.

Would you use plain javascript objects with methods, that implement the service logic, or is there a more ember-like way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Tom Dale recently put up on twitter that he wanted to propose the best way to do this - https://twitter.com/tomdale/status/457188047805624320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at the moment the best way to reuse controller code would be to use inheritence... that is, if you want common code in multiple controllers, then create a sort of abstract controller with the duplicate logic in it and then extend that for your other controllers. That's what I've done in the past and it's worked quite well for me.

I've had a similar issue with routers, though. You could always use a mixin as well.

Example:

```
  App.MyAbstractController = Em.Controller.extend({
    commonMethod: function() {
      // something common to all controllers
    }
  })

  App.ActualControllerOne = App.MyAbstractController.extend();
  App.ActualControllerTwo = App.MyAbstractController.extend();
```

Comment: Oke, It's a good idea, so I accept It. I still think however, that a service tier could be useful.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from creating your own objects and proxying things to and from them... that'd let you do a service... controllers pretty much handle the pattern of decorator-wrappering anyway, though, so you may as well inherit from a controller that has the required functionality, or use a separate controller as a proxy object for your service functionality. It'd be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

There is built in support for service layer in Emberjs even not documented now. You can use service layer based on dependency injection.

See example below. Also there is [public repository on GitHub with example](https://github.com/janmisek/ember_di_example)

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="emberjs">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ember_js_di_example</title>
     <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="./bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
     <script src="./bower_components/ember/ember.js"></script>
     <script src="./index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="Home">
    <div>
       <div>My name is <b>{{me.name}}</b></div>
       <div>My wife name is  <b>{{me.wife.name}}</b></div>
       <div>My wife name is  <b>{{wife.name}}</b> (based on controller injection)</div>
       <div>My children name is  <b>{{me.children.name}}</b></div>
    </div>
 </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{ outlet }}
 </script>
```

**index.js**

```
var Services = Ember.Namespace.create();

// service class one
Services.Me = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: function () {
        return 'Jan'
    }.property()
})

// service class two
Services.Wife = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: function () {
        return 'Sarka'
    }.property()
})

// service class three
Services.Children = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: function () {
        return 'Ondra'
    }.property()
})


App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,

    ready: function () {
        // Register service class - instance will be created on demand
        this.register('service:me', Services.Me);
        this.register('service:wife', Services.Wife);

        // Register already instantiated service
        this.register('service:children', Services.Children.create(), {instantiate: false});

        // inject service to all routes, controllers, service will be accessible as me property
        this.inject('route', 'me', 'service:me');
        this.inject('controller', 'me', 'service:me');

        // inject wife and children to me, will be accessible as wife and children property
        this.inject('service:me', 'wife', 'service:wife');
        this.inject('service:me', 'children', 'service:children');

        // inject wife only to application controller, will be accessible as wife property on home controller
        this.inject('controller:Home', 'wife', 'service:wife')
    }
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('Home', {path: '/home'});
});
```